# discord.py invite tracker unresolved reference

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

I was making a invite tracker for discord.py and i ran into this problem.

**And this is the error message:**

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\discord bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\discord bot\cogs\invite.py", line 49, in on_member_join
    await update_totals(member)
NameError: name 'update_totals' is not defined
```

Error:

```
Unresolved reference 'update_totals'(in line await update_totals(member))
```

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import aiosqlite
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class invite(commands.Cog):
    """
    Keep track of your invites
    """
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        bot.loop.create_task(self.setup())

    async def update_totals(self,member):
       invites = await member.guild.invites()

       c = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d").split("-")
       c_y = int(c[0])
       c_m = int(c[1])
       c_d = int(c[2])

       async with self.bot.db.execute("SELECT id, uses FROM invites WHERE guild_id = ?",
                              (member.guild.id,)) as cursor:  # this gets the old invite counts
         async for invite_id, old_uses in cursor:
             for invite in invites:
                if invite.id == invite_id and invite.uses - old_uses > 0:  # the count has been updated, invite is the invite that member joined by
                    if not (
                            c_y == member.created_at.year and c_m == member.created_at.month and c_d - member.created_at.day < 7):  # year can only be less or equal, month can only be less or equal, then check days
                        print(invite.id)
                        await self.bot.db.execute("UPDATE invites SET uses = uses + 1 WHERE guild_id = ? AND id = ?",
                                             (invite.guild.id, invite.id))
                        await self.bot.db.execute(
                            "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO joined (guild_id, inviter_id, joiner_id) VALUES (?,?,?)",
                            (invite.guild.id, invite.inviter.id, member.id))
                        await self.bot.db.execute(
                            "UPDATE totals SET normal = normal + 1 WHERE guild_id = ? AND inviter_id = ?",
                            (invite.guild.id, invite.inviter.id))

                    else:
                        await self.bot.db.execute(
                            "UPDATE totals SET normal = normal + 1, fake = fake + 1 WHERE guild_id = ? and inviter_id = ?",
                            (invite.guild.id, invite.inviter.id))

                    return

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self,member):
      await update_totals(member)
      await self.bot.db.commit()


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_remove(self,member):
      cur = await self.bot.db.execute("SELECT inviter_id FROM joined WHERE guild_id = ? and joiner_id = ?",
                               (member.guild.id, member.id))
      res = await cur.fetchone()
      if res is None:
        return

      inviter = res[0]

      await self.bot.db.execute("DELETE FROM joined WHERE guild_id = ? AND joiner_id = ?", (member.guild.id, member.id))
      await self.bot.db.execute("DELETE FROM totals WHERE guild_id = ? AND inviter_id = ?", (member.guild.id, member.id))
      await self.bot.db.execute("UPDATE totals SET left = left + 1 WHERE guild_id = ? AND inviter_id = ?",
                         (member.guild.id, inviter))
      await self.bot.db.commit()


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_invite_create(self,invite):
      await self.bot.db.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO totals (guild_id, inviter_id, normal, left, fake) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",
                         (invite.guild.id, invite.inviter.id, invite.uses, 0, 0))
      await self.bot.db.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO invites (guild_id, id, uses) VALUES (?,?,?)",
                         (invite.guild.id, invite.id, invite.uses))
      await self.bot.db.commit()


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_invite_delete(self, invite):
      await self.bot.db.execute("DELETE FROM invites WHERE guild_id = ? AND id = ?", (invite.guild.id, invite.id))
      await self.bot.db.commit()


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_join(self,guild):  # add new invites to monitor
      for invite in await guild.invites():
        await self.bot.db.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO invites (guild_id, id, uses), VAlUES (?,?,?)",
                             (guild.id, invite.id, invite.uses))

      await self.bot.db.commit()


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_remove(self,guild):  # remove all instances of the given guild_id
      await self.bot.db.execute("DELETE FROM totals WHERE guild_id = ?", (guild.id,))
      await self.bot.db.execute("DELETE FROM invites WHERE guild_id = ?", (guild.id,))
      await self.bot.db.execute("DELETE FROM joined WHERE guild_id = ?", (guild.id,))

      await self.bot.db.commit()



    @commands.command()
    async def inv(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
      if member is None: member = ctx.author

    # get counts
      cur = await self.bot.db.execute("SELECT normal, left, fake FROM totals WHERE guild_id = ? AND inviter_id = ?",
                               (ctx.guild.id, member.id))
      res = await cur.fetchone()
      if res is None:
        normal, left, fake = 0, 0, 0

      else:
        normal, left, fake = res

      total = normal - (left + fake)

      em = discord.Embed(
        title=f"Invites for {member.name}#{member.discriminator}",
        description=f"{member.mention} currently has **{total}** invites. (**{normal}** normal, **{left}** left, **{fake}** fake).",
        timestamp=datetime.now(),
        colour=discord.Colour.orange())

      await ctx.send(embed=em)


    async def setup(self):
      await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
      self.bot.db = await aiosqlite.connect("inviteData.db")
      await self.bot.db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS totals (guild_id int, inviter_id int, normal int, left int, fake int, PRIMARY KEY (guild_id, inviter_id))")
      await self.bot.db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS invites (guild_id int, id string, uses int, PRIMARY KEY (guild_id, id))")
      await self.bot.db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS joined (guild_id int, inviter_id int, joiner_id int, PRIMARY KEY (guild_id, inviter_id, joiner_id))")

    # fill invites if not there
      for guild in self.bot.guilds:
        for invite in await guild.invites():  # invites before bot was added won't be recorded, invitemanager/tracker don't do this
            await self.bot.db.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO invites (guild_id, id, uses) VALUES (?,?,?)",
                                 (invite.guild.id, invite.id, invite.uses))
            await self.bot.db.execute(
                "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO totals (guild_id, inviter_id, normal, left, fake) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",
                (guild.id, invite.inviter.id, 0, 0, 0))

      await self.bot.db.commit()

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("invite ready")


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(invite(bot))
```

I got the code from here where they used it in main.py while i am using it as cog.py . Any help would be much appreciated.
https://github.com/alphascriptyt/Discord_Rewrite_Tutorials/blob/master/episodes/episode-15.py

Comment: That should probably be `self.update_totals()`

Comment: aah yes i changed it to self.update_totals(member) and it worked  just after putting up the post realizing how dumb i am....

Comment: ty for your help tho